# Error in compiling on simulator using Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have recently upgraded to Xcode 5.1 and have started seeing below error while compiling my project for the iOS Simulator 7.1. Anyone have any clue about this please suggest.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker

**PS: This is happening while I am building a static library.**

[image]

Here is the detailed log:

```
Libtool /Users/abhinavgupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkjzsbxewixhinattctkwyrdqaff/Build/Products/UAT\ -\ Debug\ -\ Sandbox-iphonesimulator/libRunner.a normal i386
    cd /Users/abhinavgupta/iRunner/Code/Runner/branches/Runner_14.1_Release/client/src/Runner
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/abhinavgupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkjzsbxewixhinattctkwyrdqaff/Build/Products/UAT\ -\ Debug\ -\ Sandbox-iphonesimulator -LLinea -L/Users/abhinavgupta/iRunner/Code/Runner/branches/Runner_14.1_Release/client/src/Runner -L/Users/abhinavgupta/iRunner/Code/Runner/branches/Runner_14.1_Release/client/src/Runner/Linea -L/Users/abhinavgupta/iRunner/Code/Runner/branches/Runner_14.1_Release/client/src/Runner/ISTRemoteForms -L/Users/abhinavgupta/iRunner/Code/Runner/branches/Runner_14.1_Release/client/src/Runner/ISTCT -filelist /Users/abhinavgupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkjzsbxewixhinattctkwyrdqaff/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/UAT\ -\ Debug\ -\ Sandbox-iphonesimulator/EasyPay.build/Objects-normal/i386/Runner.LinkFileList -ObjC -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/abhinavgupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkjzsbxewixhinattctkwyrdqaff/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/UAT\ -\ Debug\ -\ Sandbox-iphonesimulator/EasyPay.build/Runner.xcent -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Security -framework ExternalAccessory -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib -framework AudioToolbox -o /Users/abhinavgupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkjzsbxewixhinattctkwyrdqaff/Build/Products/UAT\ -\ Debug\ -\ Sandbox-iphonesimulator/libRunner.a
```

Comment: First thing to do it probably identify where that is being passed in. If you go to the Log Navigator (command+8), and search for "X" or "-X", which part of the build process is it coming from?

Comment: There is nothing suspicious in the log navigator. Please see the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the entitlements from static library build process resolved this issue. Not sure how it was linked to that but removing the entitlements, provisioning profile and code signing details solved this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try Product -> Clean and restart Xcode. If it doesn't help, open ~/Libraries/Developer/Xcode folder and remove temporary files.

Comment: Tried both the options but nothing worked. From temporary files you meant derived data, right? I have removed all derived data, clean the targets and restarted the XCode. No luck!